# iOS 8 Tab bar icon color bug

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I initialise my tab bar icons on my storyboard with my custom images. When the tab bar appears on the display, it shows my images with a grey color (which is not the original color of the image)

[image]

Once i touch them, the original color appears!!

[image]

I've read that the cause could be the way i initialise my icons (in iOS 7 it works fine) but i've tried many approaches and no one was successful to solve the issue. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

try change the size of images, it must be 30x30 px for iphone